# Step by step guide to install drivers for my NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 520MX Graphics, Optimus™ technology

Tags: 13.10, nvidia-optimus

I am using Samsung NP300E5Z-S01AE Notebook and it has a NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 520MX Graphics, Optimus™ technology graphics card in it.
Please anyone tell me what's the way to install the drivers for the device on Ubuntu 13.10 (32-bit).

I have already researched on the internet but the installation guides everywhere say the same thing which is quiet hard for me to understand.
It says, that I have first to stop the X server and etc etc..., but when I try that I end up installing Ubuntu 13.10 again, because it just don't give me anything at all after doing that.

I was thinking, if someone can give some easy to understand step by step guide how to install it.... it would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the default nvidia package?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/i386/nvidia-319

Its not the newest drive found on the nvidia site;

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/67566/en-us

but its easy to install with sudo apt-get install nvidia-319

Then select the drive in System Settings/Software & Updates/Additional Drivers tab

Answer (score 0):

At first update all packages by running

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

After that

`sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms`

To delete all the nouveau driver

`sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`

Blacklisted nouveau driver in modprobe.d as

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-346_updates.conf`

And inserted :-

> ## Necessary to install nvidia drivers
>
> blacklist nouveau
>
> blacklist lbm-nouveau
>
> blacklist nvidia-173
>
> blacklist nvidia-96
>
> blacklist nvidia-current
>
> blacklist nvidia-173-updates
>
> blacklist nvidia-96-updates
>
> alias nvidia nvidia_current_updates
>
> alias nouveau off
>
> alias lbm-nouveau off
>
> options nouveau modeset=0

After that

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

And rebooted go in grub menu and set **nomodeset**

Login in text mode and stoped lightdm service by

`sudo service lightdm stop`

Go to where your .run file is located and type

`sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.82.run`
After that

`sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.82.run`

Comment: And what will happen after kernel upgrade? Black screen?

Comment: nope those packages are for building nvidia driver kernel module

Comment: why where you encountered problem ?

Comment: Did you try to install it this way or just copied a manual from somewhere? After kernel is updated, the module will be not automatically built for the new kernel and system will not boot to GUI. The newbie who follows your advice will have to go to console, learn to navigate to the installation file, if it had not been deleted, and re-install the driver. How many newbies can do it? They will just re-install Ubuntu or go back to Windows for good after such advice.

Comment: I've tried myself http://askubuntu.com/questions/651704/unable-to-load-kernel-module and i am setting this up for externel monitor setup

Comment: tested it over 14.04LTS, 14.10 and 15.04 and also with enabling multiarch support

Comment: Yes, it is a correct manual. It works... Until first kernel upgrade.

Comment: Then how would you define it ?

Comment: Define? I do not recommend to install drivers from run files. There are deb files and ppa with same drivers. If you suggest installing from ru, then you should warn that the will need to be re-installed each time the kernel updates. It more for testing.

Comment: I think the question which user has asked is according to the solution i have provided. And i know that with every kernel update the driver installation manual is not supported but at for most a way for installing any .run nvidia driver package in ubuntu. For certain deb files and ppa not have same drivers as their is some bug fixes with every release at for most nvidia provided LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER

Version: 346.87
Release Date: 2015.7.21
Operating System: Linux 64-bit