# Unable to load kernel module

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee

I've clean install ubuntu 15.04 and updated all required packages for installing:-

> **LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER**
>
> Version:  346.87
>   Release Date: 2015.7.21
>   Operating System: Linux 64-bit

And enable multi architecture support for installing nvidia 32-bit library

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

After which i've installed packages

1. `sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
2. `sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms`
3. To delete all the nouveau driver

   `sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
4. Blacklisted nouveau driver in modprobe.d as

   `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-346_updates.conf`

   And inserted :-

   ```
   #Necessary to install nvidia drivers
   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist lbm-nouveau
   blacklist nvidia-173
   blacklist nvidia-96
   blacklist nvidia-current
   blacklist nvidia-173-updates
   blacklist nvidia-96-updates
   alias nvidia nvidia_current_updates
   alias nouveau off
   alias lbm-nouveau off
   options nouveau modeset=0
   ```
5. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
6. And rebooted go in grub menu and set "nomodeset"
7. login in text mode and stoped lightdm service by

   `sudo service lightdm stop`
8. `sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.82.run`
9. `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.82.run --no-opengl-files`

The installer exit by giving error that unable to load kernel module 
Can anyone please help me describing why this error is occurring and why i am unable to install it and also how to set-up external monitor where the HDMI port is connected to NVIDIA card The external monitor connected using HDMI to DVI cable.
As i also want to get proper instruction manual for setting this type of setup. Thnxxxx in advance.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to add raring repositories to 15.04? that sounds like a recipe for trouble: 32-bit support is now provided by the mutliarch mechanism rather than the old ia32-libs package.

Comment: As i also want to install nvidia 32-bit libraries which required this therefor i installed ia32-libs

Comment: And i also tried without enabling that multiarch but still no luck

Comment: If you still facing this problem, could you [edit] question and add the complete output of `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.82.run --no-opengl-files`

Answer (score -1):

The NVidia driver version 346 is available as an Ubuntu package.

```
apt-get install nvidia-346
```

should get you going.

Comment: I know as i can use this as Propitiatory Drivers but when i am installing same driver through nvidia site why i am getting this error on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: The ubuntu package contains a lot of modifications to make the kernel module cooperate with the DKMS infrastructure. If you are interested, look at the source package and compare what you did, to see the differences

Comment: Could you provide me the link of source package

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/nvidia-346